.htaccess code, that worked on one site, not working on other
I used this .htaccess code on two different sites, to get rid of the .html endings of my domains:
RewriteEngine on

# Remove .html from the URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

# Add .html for the file request if required
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

# Handle index.html specifically to avoid /index
RewriteRule ^index$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]

I have used this exact code

on a subdomain of my own site (wonderkin.michael-aust.com)
on a another site hosted elsewhere (times-event.com)

and it worked both times.
MY code is purely HTML, CSS and JS. No Wordpress or anything else.
Problem:
Now i wanted to use this code on my main site (michael-aust.com), however it just doesn't work there.
The .html endings of my files is still always visible in the browser, even though they should not.
Any idea on why this could happen?

I asked Chat GPT for some corrections, however nothing worked.
I asked the support of my provider, because i figured it must be something related to some domain/server issue, because it had worked on other sites. However they had no real idea either.
I used the www. as an alias an changed that, because the support suggested it, but nothing changed either.


EDIT:

I checked the RewriteEngine by implementing
RewriteEngine On   RewriteRule ^test-rewrite$ test-rewrite-success.html [L]


into the .htacess and implementing a /test-rewrite-success.html on my site, which worked the redirect correctly.

I always used a fresh, anonymous Browser to test everyhing.

It was suggested, that "%{THE_REQUEST} appears to not match the given pattern, somehow" so i switched the code as follows
RewriteEngine On  RewriteRule foo https://example.com/?request=%{THE_REQUEST} [R=302,L] 


Now, when requesting michael-aust.com/foo, i get sent to example.com/?request=GET%20/foo%20HTTP/1.1

What exactly is not working? Did you check whether the file is read after all? Whether the RewriteEngine is active?

The .html endings are still always visible in the browser even though they shouldn't. I checked to see if the RewriteEngine worked and they do.

How did you check that the RewriteEngine works?

What does your browser`s network console show when you make a request? Assuming that you did use a fresh, anonymous browser to prevent looking at a client side cached results from earlier requests?

Hey guys, thank you for comments.
i checked the RewriteEngine by implementing
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test-rewrite$ test-rewrite-success.html [L]`

into the .htacess and implementing a /test-rewrite-success.html on my site.
As you can see here
https://michael-aust.com/test-rewrite
I am being correctly redirected to the minimal html i put onto the site.
If i am understanding this all correctly, the RewriteEngine ist working correctly.
I assumed that is was working correctly anyway, since the code i mentioned in my post also worked on the 2 other domains.

And what about client side cached results? I ask because you are serving static content, that most likely gets cached ...

yes i did use a fresh, anonymous Browser to prevent that

So %{THE_REQUEST} appears to not match the given pattern, somehow. Try something like RewriteRule foo https://example.com/?request=%{THE_REQUEST} [R=302,L], and then check what the resulting URL looks like, to figure out what the actual value was.

Thanks for you comment C3roe. If i understood you correctly the code should look like this?
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+).html [NC]
RewriteRule foo https://michael-aust.com/?request=%{THE_REQUEST} [R=302,L]
Add .html for the file request if required
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
Handle index.html specifically to avoid /index
RewriteRule ^index$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L]`
?
In this case nothing is happening. The URL acts normally.
https://michael-aust.com/

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

You would need to request something like https://michael-aust.com/foo, because that's what the rule was supposed to match to begin with. And do this first, before all your other rewrite stuff, otherwise it might interfere.

Thank you guys for sticking with me here.
My code now looks like this:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule foo https://example.com/?request=%{THE_REQUEST} [R=302,L]`
An when requesting
https://michael-aust.com/foo
i now get sent to
https://example.com/?request=GET%20/foo%20HTTP/1.1
I am not quite sure what this means tough?

As recommended before: add all clarification to your question by editing it
